# Why do I run out of memory using AngularJS?

Tags: angularjs

When I use `$http` to insert into the database, I am getting errors in Firefox:

> Out of memory

and

> Error: [$rootScope:infdig] 10 $digest() iterations reached. Aborting!

However, in Chrome I only see messages from my error handling code:

```
 .error(function(data, status, headers, config, statusText) {
          console.log("Status:" + status );  
          alert("algo anda mal");
    });
```

I reviewed all my services in PHP and they are OK. Is there some limit to using `$http`? I use about 25 requests at the same time. Why do I get this error?

Comment: This is to few information to actually tell you the problem. But the message means the following: I tried to do something with the value, but it changed everytime I looked at it. After 10 times I got fed up and gave up. It sounds like you're operating on the same scope variable in your $http callbacks.

Comment: @schlingel is right about your error, but this part has me worried about what else you're doing wrong: `I use about 25 requests at the same time`

Comment: My guess is that something happens like this: you change something in a scope, which triggers another scope variable to change, which triggers the first variable to change again. This is most likely happening before the AJAX requests are fulfilled.